# Guide us on or Guide us with?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

*Please Guide us on what is possbile*?

Or

*Please Guide us with what is possbile*?

Actually I am asking someone, "I want to do this. If the first option is possible, do that way. If the second option is possible, do in that way. Please guide us (with/on) what is possible"

Grammarly says both are correct. If so, what is the difference between these both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:
**guide sb (through sth)** = to explain to sb how to do sth, especially sth complicated or difficult

> Guide your students **through** the program one section at a time. (this example is from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)

in both dictionary I just could find the prepositions of "into/towards/along/around", but their application are for different meanings. and it seems the suitable one is "guide sb through sth"

> Please guide us **through** what is possible

Comment: So "Please guide us through what is possible" is the correct one than anything else?

Comment: @siddiq please take a look at "https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/guide", number 12 (If you guide someone through something that .....).

Answer (score 3):

English prepositions must be horrible for learners. (I certainly found French prepositions to be arcane.)

In some cases, only one preposition is permitted. In other cases, more than one preposition is acceptable. Moreover, I suspect that there are subtle dialectical differences between usage of prepositions: I would not dare advise you about what is accepted usage in Belfast.

My feeling is that

> Please guide us on this

and

> Please guide us about this

are both acceptable and are not necessarily asking for more than information.

> Please guide us with this

is just as acceptable, but somehow seems to me to solicit more than just information.

This very slight difference in nuance may be a regional peculiarity.